# É possível armazenar uma lista em arquivo JSON

Tags: json, lista

Estou exibindo dados que são trazidos do banco de dados em alguns *Dropdowns*, como se fosse uma espécie de pagina de carrinho de compras de sites **E-Commerce**, no momento minha pagina esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém preciso armazenar isso em uma lista cada vez que o usuário clicar no botão **Adicionar**, eu estou desenvolvendo em uma ferramenta chamada *BonitaSoft*, que é voltada para desenvolvimento de *softwares* de automação de sistemas, gostaria de saber saber se é possível armazenar essa lista de item em JSON, para depois poder exibir para o usuário em uma tabela tudo que estiver nessa lista em uma tabela.

Se tiverem algum exemplo de como salvar uma lista em JSON e como trazer o conteúdo dessa lista em uma tabela seria perfeito.

Comment: A sua dúvida é sobre fazer isso?
 https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: @Pagotti É mais ou menos isso mesmo que eu quero, mas tu saberia como posso adicionar esses itens no JSON? Pois nos exemplos mostrados no link são inseridos os itens de forma manual

Comment: Você já tem um JSON e quer alterar ele? Se é isso, complementa a sua pergunta com o código que você já fez e ai fica mais fácil entender como ajudar.

Comment: Eu não tenho ainda o JSON @Pagotti, eu consigo é salvar o conteúdo que vem do banco quando o usuário seleciona, em uma variável temporária, por isso preciso saber como adicionar o conteúdo de uma variável ao JSON

Comment: Acho que entendi, então coloca esse código JavaScript que você pega a variável que vem do banco e uma parte do HTML que tem o form e complemente a pergunta, senão o jeito é seguir o exemplo genérico daquele site.

Comment: Esse é o problema @Pagotti, essa IDE (BonitaSoft) ela não tem o código HTML, eu consigo criar as páginas apenas arrastando os campos (inputs, dropdowns, etc) pra tela, E para trazer o conteúdo do banco eu utilizo de API Rest para carregar o conteúdo na tela, exemplo de API Rest: ../API/bdm/businessData/com.company.model.ClientePostgreSQL?q=findByNomeEmpresa&p=0&c=10000&f=nomeEmpresa={{processVariable.value}}